# error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android development. I'm trying to get data from a web service with volley library but i'm getting this error

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Model class:

```
package com.example.carwashplaces;

public class ModelLocation {
    private String name, staff, latitude, longitude, id, phone, comment;

    public ModelLocation() {

    }

    public ModelLocation(String name, String staff, String latitude,String    longitude, String id, String phone, String comment) {
        this.name = name;
        this.staff = staff;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.id = id;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStaff() {
        return staff;
    }

    public void setStaff(String staff) {
        this.staff = staff;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

Task class:

```
package com.example.carwashplaces;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BackgroundTask {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelLocation> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String json_url = "http://developer.byethost14.com/location.php";

    public BackgroundTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<ModelLocation> getLocationArrayList() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new   JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                       int count = 0;
                       while (count < response.length()){
                           try {
                               JSONObject jsonObject =    response.getJSONObject(count);
                               ModelLocation modelLocation = new   ModelLocation(jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("name"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("latitude"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("longitude"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("staff"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("comment"),
                                       jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                               locationArrayList.add(modelLocation);
                               count++;
                           } catch (JSONException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error...",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonArrayRequest);

        return locationArrayList;
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Nakuru",
      "latitude":"-0.28333",
      "longitude":"36.06667",
      "staff":"Elias Baya",
      "phone":"712695820",
      "comment":"Have a capacity of five cars at a go"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Nairobi station",
      "latitude":"-1.28333",
      "longitude":"36.81667",
      "staff":"Elias David",
      "phone":"796268509",
      "comment":"Second car wash to be launched in 2000"
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Nyeri Station",
      "latitude":"-0.437099",
      "longitude":"36.95801",
      "staff":"Faith Neema",
      "phone":"726774112",
      "comment":"one of our best car wash"
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "name":"Mombasa station",
      "latitude":"-4.05466",
      "longitude":"39.66359",
      "staff":"Neema Elias",
      "phone":"710723308",
      "comment":"welcome all to mombasa station"
   },
   {
      "id":"5",
      "name":"Malindi Station",
      "latitude":"-3.21799",
      "longitude":"40.11692",
      "staff":"Baya Elias",
      "phone":"720038783",
      "comment":"launched in 2010 december"
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi Elias. It would be very useful if you could post the entire error you're getting back, and not just 1 line for it.

Comment: Hi, and Congratulations on your first question on SO! :) Your code looks good, but the server returns an incorrect answer (redirect). This seems to be the problem. Pay attention to the logcat. And I fully agree with @TooManyEduardos.

Comment: Okay now here is the error from logcat ave$a: IO Exception opening: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/android/editors/slides/client_flags?1568445343195= stream was reset: CANCEL

Comment: @TooManyEduardos The error is not from logcat it's the build out or something of the sort... When I try to build the app a got the error as a build result..

Comment: if that's the case, and you're using Android Studio, you should get a line number or a sign of where the error is.
Do you have that?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos The 3rd parameter of the jsonarrayRequest function where null is cast to a String...

Comment: oh, duh. you can't cast null to a String.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Okay how should i put it because when I leave it without a cast it throws an error demanding for a cast

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, there is no problem with the code. This is an extra protection that has been added deliberately by byethost.com to block bots from accessing our sites resulting in huge security benefits to our scripts. I reuploaded these files into 000webhost.com and it worked like a charm. For further information, refer this discussion ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String